# Wordpress - how to search pages only

Tags: wordpress, search

I need a little help on Wordpress searching. The thing I want to know is how to search Wordpress pages only.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out this [page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-search-results-to-custom-post-type) on the wordpress forums.
You have to add a hidden form field in your search form and add a hook to update the query that wordpress generates.

Edit: Here's the code from the forum post mentioned above.

In the search form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="page" />
```

In functions.php:

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {
    $post_type = $_GET['type'];
    if (!$post_type) {
        $post_type = 'any';
    }
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
    };
    return $query;
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your search.php, find The Loop and insert this code just after it. You can recognize the Loop because it usually starts with:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
```

***Code to be inserted:***

```
if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='post')) continue;
```

So, your code should be like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<?php if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='post')) continue; ?>
```

Let me know if it worked.